# App is force closing when i run it? Unable to start activity?

Tags: android, logcat

When i run it i get an immediate force close. I can never understand the logcat errors. I am using Eclipse along with the Android SDK. Here is the Logcat error but what does it mean?

```
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{izzy.n/izzy.n.IzzynActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:684)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-29 12:59:35.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9759):     at android.view.Layout
02-29 12:59:43.347: I/Process(9759): Sending signal. PID: 9759 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for the Help anyone

and here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        layout="@layout/main" />




 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="izzy.n"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.notes"
            android:label="@string/notes"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Enter Your code or include layout file its works nice

Comment: Or make sure that your activity is actually in your app's manifest.

Comment: Please also post your manifest.

Comment: i updated the question please check the manifest and tell me if anything is wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the filename of your XML file?

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    layout="@layout/main" />
```

includes the layout `main`.  If this is in this file `main.xml`, that is your problem.  If it's not, can you post your onCreate method so we can see how you are inflating this view?

this is a problem because the `<include/>` tag will inflate a layout into the current layout.  If you are trying to inflate `@layout/main` into `@layout/main`, this will cause infinite recursion and is not valid.  I am not sure what you are trying to do, are you trying to draw the same layout twice?  If so, try creating a `main_component.xml` layout, and using `<include/>` in `main.xml` to inflate that layout.

Comment: why would main.xml be a problem, and yes it is

Comment: remove the `<include ... />` element from the xml file, and try it.